# Succulent weed identification

Tags: species-identification, botany

There is a succulent-looking weed growing in a crack in my driveway. What is it?

- **Conditions:** Dry, full sun, asphalt & gravel, no competition.
- **Date:** 2018-07-16
- **Location:** Toronto, Ontario, Canada
- **Size:** 40cm x 40cm x 2cm

[image]

Comment: I am not familair with the flora of the New World, but this looks like Common purslane, Portulaca oleracea

Comment: @RHA is correct, it is *Portulaca oleracea* (RHA you should put this as an answer).  This is purslane in one of its favorite and classic environments, a driveway crack!  If this specimen has not been sprayed, you might taste a few leaves -- people put it in salads. And if don't want it around, pull it now, it is about to bloom and the seeds will be abundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Common purslane, *Portulaca oleracea*. It is used in salads, although it contains oxalic acid and there are poisenous plants resembling Purslane, see comment below.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portulaca_oleracea

Comment: An acquaintance advised me of this: *1) Make sure you can distinguish it from hairy-stemmed spurge (which is poisonous) 2) Purslane contains oxalic acid, so those at risk of kidney stones should not eat too much!* More info here: https://jstookey.com/node/214